# What does it mean geometrically for a matrix to satisfy its characteristic equation or to satisfy the Cayley-Hamiltonian theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, cayley-hamilton

I am a high schooler who has just recently learned a bit about matrices and the Cayley-Hamiltonian theorem. And my teachers have told me that to get the characteristic equation of many matrix $A$, I have to solve for det.$[A-\lambda I] = 0$ where $I$ is the identity matrix of same order as that of $A$.

So what does it mean geometrically for a matrix $A$ to satisfy the cayley hamiltonian theorem ? like if the above mentioned determinant is zero then as per my understanding, if we apply the above matrix as a linear transformation then it will squish everything down to just a single line.

What does it mean geometrically when we get a value of lambda that isn't purely real ?
Say for example if we get $\lambda = 3 + 4\iota$, then what would that mean ?

Comment: As a high schooler start first with an example yourself, i.e., with a $2\times 2$-matrix. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) for an example and how to do it. After your own calculation with an example, many of your questions will clarify. If not, then a more precise  question makes sense. To your title question: Cayley-Hamilton means that the minimal polynomial of a square matrix divides its characteristic polynomial.

Comment: I think you should explain what you mean by "geometric".

Comment: @Argyll I have given as an example that what do I understand if a determinant is zero. Like that is there any way to interpret it visually ?